# Google Geocoding API error: You are over your quota

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I´m working with google maps, and i have problems with my quota. How can i fix this?

the message i got from my hompage is:

> Google Geocoding API error: You are over your quota

I read thats something with the daily limit of 2500 pr. IP. on the page where the message comes up there is about 40 firms that are getting shown, so i dont now if it is something with the number of firms on the page, so that there are to many request for the page and some of it gets blocked.

Link to the page: [My page](http://ribeby.dk/index.php/borgerservice-i-ribe/slideshow)

What can i do. Any help will be appreciated.

Regards
Ivan.

Answer (score 2):

There's a limit of 2,500 geolocation requests per day. AFter this limit, you'll get such error .

*Usage Limits
Use of the Google Geocoding API is subject to a query limit of 2,500 geolocation requests per day. (User of Google Maps API for Business may perform up to 100,000 requests per day.) This limit is enforced to prevent abuse and/or repurposing of the Geocoding API, and this limit may be changed in the future without notice. Additionally, we enforce a request rate limit to prevent abuse of the service. If you exceed the 24-hour limit or otherwise abuse the service, the Geocoding API may stop working for you temporarily. If you continue to exceed this limit, your access to the Geocoding API may be blocked.*

Status code: "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" indicates that you are over your quota.

Comment: Hi user1283565. I have seen those numbers before. But how much does the business solution cost, i cant see it any where.

Comment: Can see the cost here http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps-faq.html it very expensive.

Comment: You pay by usage, though there is a floor. I'd contact sales and see what it will cost.

Answer (score 0):

> "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" indicates that you are over your quota.

for more information please visit this URL "**https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#StatusCodes**"